# display 3rd level dropdown submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I want have 3rd submenu, but I don't want exactly, which code I need add, because I think that I have code for 3rd submenu but unlikely is not working.

```
    .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: inherit;
    z-index: 1000;
    width:1010px;

    }
    .menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 60px;
    }
    .menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    position: relative;
    }
    .menu ul li a:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -32px;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    /* Rotate */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* Rotate Origin */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    }
    .menu ul li:first-child a:before,
    .menu ul ul li a:before {
    display: none
    }
    .menu ul li.active a,
    .menu ul li a:hover,
    .menu ul li a.selected {
    color: #ff6760
    }
    .menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 168px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
    .menu ul li ul:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff6760;
    }
    .menu ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #313131;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    }
    .menu ul li ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid #ff6760
    }
    .menu ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0
    }
    .menu ul li ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 13px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    }
    .menu ul li.active ul li a {
    color: #dfdfdf
    }
    .menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff6760;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    }
    .menu ul li.active ul li a,
    .menu ul li ul li a:hover,
    .menu ul li ul li a.selected {
    border: none
    }
    * html .menu {
    height: 1%
    }
    .selectnav {
    display: none;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent url(style/images/dropdown-arrow.png) no-repeat right center;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-size: 30px 28px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    @media only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-moz-        min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) { 
    .selectnav {
        background-image: url(style/images/dropdown-arrow@2x.png)
    }
}

and html : 

            <li><a href="#">NaĹˇe herne</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HerĹa 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FotogĂˇlerie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ponuka prĂˇce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Novinky</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">HerĹa 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FotogĂˇlerie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ponuka prĂˇce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Novinky</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">HerĹa 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FotogĂˇlerie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ponuka prĂˇce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Novinky</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

            </li>
```

So, as you can see I have css code for 3rd submenu, but isnt working, I don't know why, but I cant get it working my myself, so I'm trying to ask here.

Comment: Use the same CSS Logic that you have used for the second dropdown menu. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wss5A/111/)**

**CSS**

```
* {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:1em;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#menu{
    margin:3px;
}

#menu > li{            /* Top Level */
    float:left;
    margin-right:3px;
}
#menu > li > span{
    display:block;
    background:#0ac;
    padding:3px 10px;
}
#menu > li:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
}

#menu > li > ul{        /* Second Level */
    display:none;
    background:#08a;
}
#menu > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
#menu > li > ul > li > span{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-top:solid 3px #fff;
}
#menu > li > ul > li:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
}

#menu > li > ul li > ul{   /* Third Level & beyond */
    display:none;
    background:#068;
}
#menu > li > ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    border-left:solid 3px #fff;
    top:0;
    width:auto;
}
#menu > li > ul > li ul > li{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-top:solid 3px #fff;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#menu > li > ul > li ul > li:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Nathan Lee said, use the same logic that you have used for second drop down menu. Otherwise follow 
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvarajcp/8Lrwq/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#menu{width:484px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #000; height:25px;}
#menu ul{list-style-type:none;}
#menu ul li{float: left; position: relative;}
#menu ul li:hover{background-color: #999;}
#menu ul li a{color: #fff; padding: 0 30px; line-height:25px; font-size:11px; font-family:arial; display: block; text-decoration:none;}
#menu ul li a:hover{background-color: #999;}
#menu ul li ul li{float: none; position: relative;}
#menu ul li ul{position: absolute; top:25px; left:0; display: none; background-color: #000; width:150px;}
#menu ul li:hover > ul{display: block;}
#menu ul li ul li a{white-space: nowrap; line-height:25px;}
#menu ul li ul li ul{position: absolute; top:0; left:145px; display: none; background-color: #000; width:150px;}
```